# Error in Cron Job

Tags: magento-2.1

I have setup cron job for `google shopping` data feeds from the admin but I am getting this error:

> Last cron task is older than one hour. Please check your settings and
>   your configuration!

The cron job is not running. Can anyone suggest the solution for the cron job?

Please check screenshot for error:

[image]

Please check my configuration:
[image]

My magento version: 2.1.5

Answer (score 1):

Have you set cron on server side?

From ssh as your magento file system owner you can run "crontab -e" and add the below however make sure to update all instances of paths (var/www/magento2) to your magento installation.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

See here for more information: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html